# Unique Solution with period $1$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

For any continuous function $f(z)$ of period $1$. Show that $\varphi'=2\pi \varphi+f(t)$ has a unique solution of period $1$.

Is this problem wrong with the counter example $\varphi(t)=e^{2\pi t}$. Shall we change it into  $\varphi'=2\pi i\varphi+f(t)$

Comment: Does $e^{2\pi t}$ have period $1$? What's $f(t)$ to make that counterexample work?

Comment: The problem doesn't assert the differential equation has a unique solution: it merely asserts that amongst all solutions, exactly one of them has $1$ as a period.

Comment: If $f\equiv 0$, the (unique) periodic solution is $\varphi\equiv 0$. So this is not a counterexample.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look for a solution $\varphi(t) = z(t)\exp(2\pi t)$, then
$$
z'(t) = f(t) \exp(-2\pi t)\\
z(t) = z(0) + \int_0^t f(s) \exp(-2\pi s) ds\\
\varphi(t) = \varphi(0)\exp(2\pi t)+ \int_0^t f(s) \exp(2\pi (t-s))ds
$$

Now if the solution is 1 periodic:
$$
\varphi(0) =\varphi(1)\\
 = \varphi(0)\exp(2\pi )+ \int_0^1 f(s) \exp(2\pi (1-s))ds
$$gives you an unique possibility for $\varphi(0)=y_0$.

Now, for such a solution
$$
\varphi'(t) = 2\pi\varphi + f(t), \varphi(0)=y_0\\
\frac d{dt}\varphi(t+1) = \varphi'(t+1)
 = 2\pi\varphi(t+1) + f(t+1), \varphi(0+1)=\varphi(1)=y_0\\
$$
as the solution of the Cauchy problem is unique, then $\varphi(t+1)=\varphi(t)$.

This solution is then a 1 periodic solution.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is a solution of the boundary value problem on $[0,1]$ with periodic boundary condition: $\varphi(1)=\varphi(0)$. It helps to focus on the map $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ defined by  $T: \varphi(0)  \mapsto  \varphi(1)  $. You should check that:

1. $T$ is injective. This follows from the uniqueness of the IVP with initial condition  specified at $1$.
2. $T$ is an affine map: $Tx=ax+b$ where $a,b$ are constant. Indeed,  $b$ is what you get from $\varphi(0)=0$. The linearity follows from the equation being linear in $\varphi$. The constant $a$ has nothing to do with $f$, it comes from the homogeneous equation $\varphi'=2\pi \varphi$. You can and should write it down explicitly.
3. Key point: $a\ne 1$.

Conclude that there is a unique $x\in\mathbb R$ such that $Tx=x$.

Comment: I wrote this in a more convoluted way than is really necessary, but  this strategy also applies to ODE of higher orders. Then $T$ is an affine map between Euclidean spaces: $Tx=Ax+b$,  and the key point 3 is the invertibility of $A-I$.